# Как скопировать форму вместе с динамически вычисляемым для полей value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице происходят расчеты, выводятся в форму, а именно в текстовые поля.
Затем мне нужно получить всю форму с результатами. Проблема в том, что `html()`  не берет значения (`value`) текстовых полей после расчета.

Пробовал сделать подобное

```js
var res = 5 + 15;
$("#res").val(res)

$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var code = $("#wrapp").html();
  $("#wrapp2").html(code)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapp">
  <input type="text" id="res" />
  <button id="btn1">Click</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapp2"></div>
```

Так не работает. Вычисленные значения `value` не переносятся в скопированную форму.

Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки (пример выше) появлялась форма с заполненными значениями.

Comment: Если бы вы сделали простейший примерчик на jsfiddle или любом другом ресурсе было бы замечательно и намного нагляднее =)

Comment: что не работает? как не работает? какое поведение ожидалось?

Comment: Обновил,теперь там есть пирмер

Comment: а зачем вам дублировать форму?

Comment: Вопрос не в этом,а как одним махом все взять))

Comment: $.prop() используй

Comment: нет, вопрос именно в этом, судя по всему вы пытаетесь решить какую-то проблему, очевидно, что пошли неверным путем, но без указания какую именно проблему вы решаете довольно тяжело определить что именно нужно делать на самом деле

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, чем тут поможет `prop`?

Comment: копирование плохо хотя бы потому, что `id` должен быть уникальным на странице, а при копировании в примере они начинают дублироваться

Comment: id это для примера в jsfiddle ,и не на этой странице будет,потом это все через `htmlspecialchars` и в базу

Comment: вооот еще хуже :-) какой смысл хранить в базе _разметку_ формы со значениями если можно хранить _только_ значения? В любом случае даже сейчас очевидно что копировать ничего не надо

Comment: Слишком большая разновидность форм,в некоторых количество полей не статично,а зависит от пользователя

Comment: что не отменяет факто того, что глупо хранить _разметку формы со значениями_ **вместо** одних значений

Comment: если давать формальный ответ, на пример ссылка на который дана в вопросе, то здесь хватит функции [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) но судя по комментариям вам нужно совсем не это

Comment: $.appendTo ещё можно если я правильно понял вопрос, хотя он такой размытый, что фиг поймешь что хочет автор

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то что то такое

```js
(function($) {

  newEl = function() {
    console.log('test');
    var sample = $(".sample:first-child").clone();
    sample.on("click", newEl);
    sample.appendTo(".inner");
  }
  $('.sample').on("click", newEl);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inner">
  <input class="sample" type="text" />
</div>
```